# Python http server with multithreaded response handlers

Tags: python, multithreading, http, basehttpserver

I'm trying to setup a python server that handles POST packets.
Once a packet arrives, The do_POST inits a new thread with self & some data,
then, the thread does some stuff and puts into the self object received the output.
this is what I have so far:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
....
class httpHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        length = int(self.headers['content-length'])
        data = self.rfile.read(length)
        Resolver(self,data).start()
        return
```

Then, In my resolver class I do:
import threading

```
class Resolver(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,http,number):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.http = http
        self.number = number + "!"

    def run(self):
        self.http.send_response(200)
        self.http.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.http.send_header('Content-length', len(self.number))
        self.http.end_headers()
        # Send the html message
        self.http.wfile.write(self.number)
        return
```

Of course, this is an example and not the complete sheet, I'm still in the phase of testing my program.
It will be running over a weak platform (at the moment, Raspberry pi) and I'm looking for a good performance solution.
any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you really need this to be a thread per request instead of a thread per connection (which could just use the builtin `TheadingMixIn` instead of trying to implement it manually)?

Comment: Well, The big scope is this: My main class which runs the connection holds a db connection (using pycopg2 module) and each new post packet arrives receives a cursor. then, the request gets analyzed and the output is then returned in the response packet. I read somewhere that ThreadingMixIn is very slow. So Im afraid to rely on that. Correct me if Im wrong.  Each connection is usually very short: Request something, get the result and finish

Comment: Using multiple threads in Python is not generally great in general.  But if the purpose of the thread is to talk to a database connection then at least while each request handler is talking to the database it should allow other threads to run.  Trying to do it yourself is not going to make it any faster :/

Comment: Using multiple threads in Python is great if you're just using it to do lots of I/O-bound stuff concurrently. It sucks if you're trying to get do lots of CPU-bound stuff in parallel and get the benefits of a multi-core system. It doesn't matter whether you use `ThreadingMixIn` or your own threading code; the exact same will always be true. But `ThreadingMixIn` still has an advantage: it's a trivial change to swap it for `ForkingMixIn`, and that's certainly not true for custom code written around the `threading` module…

Comment: Plus custom written code is much, much more likely to be buggy, especially if you're new to dealing with concurrency.

Comment: By the way, accepting and responding to HTTP requests and talking to a database server all counts as I/O-bound stuff. But "the request gets analyzed" might count as CPU-bound. If you don't really understand the difference, I'd suggest trying threading first, and if you end up with the server falling behind the clients and using 100% of one core and 0% of the rest… you need forking.

Comment: @Iguananaut: Great point. And yet another reason to use WSGI or Tornado or whatever; there's a whole lot less of the hard stuff for you to get wrong.

Comment: I will look into it. I need to find a few examples about tornado to see what Im going into. Could it be easier to do this solution in PHP server? in terms of threading, database access speeds and memory/cpu usage

Comment: @e-r-a-n: The only reason anything could be easier in PHP instead of Python is if you know PHP much better than you know Python. If you think embedded PHP is easier than PHP CGI… well, you can do embedded Python. But it's even simpler to use WSGI (or CGI if you're forced to). Either way, the server handles the threading, the relevant PHP or Python module handles the database; memory, CPU, etc. are probably not important unless your code is doing something heavy, in which case it's your only code that matters; etc.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` expects you to be done with the request by the time you return from `do_POST`. This isn't all that clear in the documentation, but it's immediately obvious if you look at the source to [`handle_one_request`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/BaseHTTPServer.py#l301), the method that calls your method:

```
mname = 'do_' + self.command
# ...
method = getattr(self, mname)
mname()
self.wfile.flush() #actually send the response if not already done.
```

If you look deeper, you'll see that, as you'd expect, the code expects to be able to close or reuse the connection as soon as it finishes handling a request.

So, you can't use `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` this way.

You can, of course, write your own handler implementation instead. To a large extent, the stuff in `BaseHTTPServer` is meant as sample code more than as a powerful, efficient, robust, and flexible framework (which is why the docs link straight to the source).

Alternatively, instead of trying to create a thread per request, just create a thread per connection. The [`ThreadingMixIn`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#asynchronous-mixins) class makes this easy.

But an even better solution would be to use a better framework, like Twisted or Tornado, or to use a webserver that does the threading for you and just calls your code via WSGI.

Comment: I will add +1 for Tornado BTW as it is very easy to get started with.

Comment: What kind of server that runs my python code trough WSGI? I dont know much of it. Do you mean PHP/Apache server? Should I get started with Tornado instead of BaseHTTPServer classes of python? And, also..Tornado is a better framework than ThreadingMixIn?

Comment: Well, there's no need to use "PHP/Apache". Apache without the PHP modules will do just as well, since you're not trying to run any PHP code. So will nginx, or anything else. You may even have a server built in on the device that you just need to configure (or at worst add a WSGI module to).

Comment: Thank you. I will start with ThreadingMixIn. I dont know anything about WSGI. Since I dont need much from the  web services modules, Maybe its not so important ThreadMixIn or Tornado

Comment: @e-r-a-n: WSGI is basically a better version of CGI. You have a web server that handles connections, async/threading/forking, etc. When users hit a certain URL, it runs your Python script to generate the response, and that script is the only code you have to write.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way to do this.  Now each thread that you send a request to is just going to be writing responses through the HTTP server "simultaneously".  You could add locking but that that would still defeat the purpose basically.

Python already comes with a simple built-in way to do this.  `BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer` is a subclass of `SocketServer.TCPServer` so you can just use `SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn`.  The Python docs give an example here:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#asynchronous-mixins

I'm sure there already exist examples of how to do this on SO too.